# JSON Query that work in ASP.NET is not working in ASP.NET-Core 3.0 to retun query of fields from DB to User Form

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Basically Below Script and related Action Result worked in in ASP.Net but does not work in ASP.Net-Core 2.2 or 3.0.

Apparently Newtosoft JSON is not fully Supported in ASP.Net-Core 3.0 or I do not know how convert for use.

I am not getting an Error ..., The Form just never populates.

I have Copied View and Controllers between .Net version with the same result.

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult GetProductByID1(string id)
{
    int AvProdId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    // According id to query the database and get the relevant values. 
    var query = _context.AvProducts.Where(c => c.AvProductId == AvProdId)
        .Select(c =>
        new
        {
            c.AvProductId,
            ProductName = c.ProductName,
            ProductDesc = c.ProductDesc,
            ProductComplexityFac = c.ProductComplexityFac,
            ProductComplexityBase = c.ProductComplexityBase,
            TotalComplexity = c.TotalComplexity,
            Component1Desc = c.Component1Desc,
            Component2Desc = c.Component2Desc,
            Component3Desc = c.Component3Desc,
            Component4Desc = c.Component4Desc,
            Component5Desc = c.Component5Desc,
            Component6Desc = c.Component6Desc,
            Component7Desc = c.Component7Desc,
            Component8Desc = c.Component8Desc,
            Component9Desc = c.Component9Desc,
            Component10Desc = c.Component10Desc,
            Component11Desc = c.Component11Desc,
            Component12Desc = c.Component12Desc,
            Component13Desc = c.Component13Desc,
            Component14Desc = c.Component14Desc,
            Component15Desc = c.Component15Desc,
            ComponentComplexityFac1 = c.ComponentComplexityFac1,
            ComponentComplexityFac2 = c.ComponentComplexityFac2,
            ComponentComplexityFac3 = c.ComponentComplexityFac3,
            ComponentComplexityFac4 = c.ComponentComplexityFac4,
            ComponentComplexityFac5 = c.ComponentComplexityFac5,
            ComponentComplexityFac6 = c.ComponentComplexityFac6,
            ComponentComplexityFac7 = c.ComponentComplexityFac7,
            ComponentComplexityFac8 = c.ComponentComplexityFac8,
            ComponentComplexityFac9 = c.ComponentComplexityFac9,
            ComponentComplexityFac10 = c.ComponentComplexityFac10,
            ComponentComplexityFac11 = c.ComponentComplexityFac11,
            ComponentComplexityFac12 = c.ComponentComplexityFac12,
            ComponentComplexityFac13 = c.ComponentComplexityFac13,
            ComponentComplexityFac14 = c.ComponentComplexityFac14,
            ComponentComplexityFac15 = c.ComponentComplexityFac15
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(query);
}
```

Script: from View that populates User form based on DropDownlist Selection

```
@* Product #1 Calc*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#AvProductId").change(function () {
          //  alert($(this).val() + " " + $(this).find("option:selected").html());
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductByID1", "SizingUserDashBoard")',
                data: '{id: "' + id + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data.LastName);
                    //$("#txtAvProdId").val(data.AvProductId);
                    //$("#txtProductName1").val(data.ProductName);
                    //$("#txtProductDesc1").val(data.ProductDesc);
                    //$("#txtProductComplexityFac1").val(data.ProductComplexityFac);
                    //$("#txtProductComplexityBase1").val(data.ProductComplexityBase);
                    //$("#txtTotalComplexity1").val(data.TotalComplexity);
                    //$("#txtComponent1Desc1").val(data.Component1Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent2Desc1").val(data.Component2Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent3Desc1").val(data.Component3Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent4Desc1").val(data.Component4Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent5Desc1").val(data.Component5Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent6Desc1").val(data.Component6Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent7Desc1").val(data.Component7Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent8Desc1").val(data.Component8Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent9Desc1").val(data.Component9Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent10Desc1").val(data.Component10Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent11Desc1").val(data.Component11Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent12Desc1").val(data.Component12Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent13Desc1").val(data.Component13Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent14Desc1").val(data.Component14Desc);
                    //$("#txtComponent15Desc1").val(data.Component15Desc);
                   @* $("#TestProdDesc12").val(data.Component12Desc);
                    $("#TestProdDesc13").val(data.Component13Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent2Desc").val($("#txtComponent2Desc1").val());
                    $("#Prod1Compnent3Desc").val($("#txtComponent3Desc1").val());*@

                    //$("#TestProdDesc12").val($("#txtComponent12Desc1").val());
                    //$("#TestProdDesc13").val($("#txtComponent13Desc1").val());

                    $("#DescProduct_1").val(data.ProductName);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent1Desc").val(data.Component1Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent2Desc").val(data.Component2Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent3Desc").val(data.Component3Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent4Desc").val(data.Component4Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent5Desc").val(data.Component5Desc);

                    $("#Prod1Compnent6Desc").val(data.Component6Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent7Desc").val(data.Component7Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent8Desc").val(data.Component8Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent9Desc").val(data.Component9Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent10Desc").val(data.Component10Desc);

                    $("#Prod1Compnent11Desc").val(data.Component11Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent12Desc").val(data.Component12Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent13Desc").val(data.Component13Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent14Desc").val(data.Component14Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent15Desc").val(data.Component15Desc);


                    $("#Compnent1Desc").val(data.Component1Desc);
                    $("#Compnent2Desc").val(data.Component2Desc);
                    $("#Compnent3Desc").val(data.Component3Desc);
                    $("#Compnent4Desc").val(data.Component4Desc);
                    $("#Compnent5Desc").val(data.Component5Desc);
                    $("#Compnent6Desc").val(data.Component6Desc);
                    $("#Compnent7Desc").val(data.Component7Desc);
                    $("#Compnent8Desc").val(data.Component8Desc);
                    $("#Compnent9Desc").val(data.Component9Desc);
                    $("#Compnent10Desc").val(data.Component10Desc);
                    $("#Compnent11Desc").val(data.Component11Desc);
                    $("#Compnent12Desc").val(data.Component12Desc);
                    $("#Compnent13Desc").val(data.Component13Desc);
                    $("#Compnent14Desc").val(data.Component14Desc);
                    $("#Compnent15Desc").val(data.Component15Desc);

                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac1_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac1);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac2_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac2);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac3_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac3);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac4_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac4);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac5_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac5);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac6_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac6);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac7_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac7);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac8_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac8);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac9_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac9);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac10_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac10);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac11_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac11);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac12_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac12);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac13_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac13);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac14_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac14);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac15_1").val(data.ComponentComplexityFac15);



                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve Products.');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lowercase initial letter of `data.property` and change the url like below:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#AvProductId").change(function () {      
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductByID1", "SizingUserDashBoard")'+'?id='+id,
               //data: '{id: "' + id + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#DescProduct_1").val(data.productName);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent1Desc").val(data.component1Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent2Desc").val(data.component2Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent3Desc").val(data.component3Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent4Desc").val(data.component4Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent5Desc").val(data.component5Desc);

                    $("#Prod1Compnent6Desc").val(data.component6Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent7Desc").val(data.component7Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent8Desc").val(data.component8Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent9Desc").val(data.component9Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent10Desc").val(data.component10Desc);

                    $("#Prod1Compnent11Desc").val(data.component11Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent12Desc").val(data.component12Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent13Desc").val(data.component13Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent14Desc").val(data.component14Desc);
                    $("#Prod1Compnent15Desc").val(data.component15Desc);

                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac1_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac1);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac2_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac2);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac3_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac3);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac4_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac4);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac5_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac5);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac6_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac6);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac7_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac7);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac8_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac8);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac9_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac9);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac10_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac10);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac11_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac11);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac12_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac12);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac13_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac13);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac14_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac14);
                    $("#Prod1ComponentComplexityFac15_1").val(data.componentComplexityFac15);
                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve Products.');
                }
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer...., It worked and was exactly what I needed

Comment: Sorry it took me so Long to Respond...., was dedicating Cycles to another Project